# Syntax for unbalanced block design with nesting?

Tags: lme4-nlme, experiment-design, biostatistics, nested-data, blocking

I am trying to run a model in which I have site as a blocking factor, and two layers of nested random effects due to sub-sampling.
The nesting layers are -> plant[flower[robbing status]].
My response is pollen tube number.

Does this look correct?

```
lmer(tubes ~ status + (1|flower) + (1|plant) + site, data=data)
```

Dummy data:

1. site-plant-flower--status-tubes
2. sk----1----1-------y------40
3. sk----1----2-------n------74
4. sk----1----3-------y------76
5. sk----1----4-------n------67
6. sk----2----1-------y------2
7. sk----2----2-------n------73
8. sk----2----3-------y------51
9. sk----2----4-------n------46
10. ...
11. pg----1----1-------y------71
12. pg----1----2-------n------68
13. pg----1----3-------y------40
14. pg----1----4-------n------48
15. pg----2----1-------y------48
16. pg----2----2-------n------53
17. pg----2----3-------y------34
18. pg----2----4-------n------48